# opentsdb with standalone hbase not able to run tsd

Tags: hadoop, hbase, opentsdb

Following are the detail of the setup
Hbase 1.2.6.1 (installed through Homebrew, running in standalone mode)
Following is detail of the hbase-site.xml

```
<name>hbase.rootdir</name>

<value>file:///Users/sangy/hbase</value>
```

```
<name>hbase.zookeeper.property.dataDir</name>

<value>/Users/sangy/zookeeper</value>
```

hbase.unsafe.stream.capability.enforce

false

OpenTSDB(version=2.3.1, installed through Homebrew)

Following is openTsdb.conf

file

```
# --------- NETWORK ----------

# The TCP port TSD should use for communications

# *** REQUIRED ***

tsd.network.port = 4242

# The IPv4 network address to bind to, defaults to all addresses

# tsd.network.bind = 0.0.0.0
# Disable Nagel's algorithm, default is True
#tsd.network.tcp_no_delay = true
# Determines whether or not to send keepalive packets to peers, default
# is True
#tsd.network.keep_alive = true
# Determines if the same socket should be used for new connections, default
# is True
#tsd.network.reuse_address = true



# Number of worker threads dedicated to Netty, defaults to # of CPUs * 2

#tsd.network.worker_threads = 8



# Whether or not to use NIO or tradditional blocking IO, defaults to True

#tsd.network.async_io = true



# ----------- HTTP -----------

# The location of static files for the HTTP GUI interface.

# *** REQUIRED ***

tsd.http.staticroot = /Users/sangy/tools/opentsdb/static/



# Where TSD should write it's cache files to

# *** REQUIRED ***

tsd.http.cachedir = /tmp/opentsdb



# --------- CORE ----------

# Whether or not to automatically create UIDs for new metric types, default

# is False

#tsd.core.auto_create_metrics = false



# Full path to a directory containing plugins for OpenTSDB

tsd.core.plugin_path = /Users/sangy/tools/opentsdb/plugins



# --------- STORAGE ----------

# Whether or not to enable data compaction in HBase, default is True

#tsd.storage.enable_compaction = true



# How often, in milliseconds, to flush the data point queue to storage,

# default is 1,000

# tsd.storage.flush_interval = 1000



# Name of the HBase table where data points are stored, default is "tsdb"

#tsd.storage.hbase.data_table = tsdb



# Name of the HBase table where UID information is stored, default is "tsdb-uid"

#tsd.storage.hbase.uid_table = tsdb-uid



# Path under which the znode for the -ROOT- region is located, default is "/hbase"

#tsd.storage.hbase.zk_basedir = /hbase



# A comma separated list of Zookeeper hosts to connect to, with or without

# port specifiers, default is "localhost"

tsd.storage.hbase.zk_quorum = localhost
```

Java Version : 1.8.0_152

Its running on Operating system:macOS High Sierra (10.13.6)

Java Process Running is

53745 HMaster

23266 DataNode

23162 NameNode

23404 SecondaryNameNode

23596 ResourceManager

53900 Jps

The problem I am facing is I am not able to start TSD

Command I am using to start TSD is

tsdb tsd --config=/Users/sangy/tools/opentsdb/opentsdb.conf

I am getting following exception

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.RuntimeException: Initialization failed

at net.opentsdb.tools.TSDMain.main(TSDMain.java:237)

Caused by: com.stumbleupon.async.DeferredGroupException: At least one of the Deferreds failed, first exception:

at com.stumbleupon.async.DeferredGroup.done(DeferredGroup.java:169)

at com.stumbleupon.async.DeferredGroup.recordCompletion(DeferredGroup.java:142)

at com.stumbleupon.async.DeferredGroup.access$000(DeferredGroup.java:36)

at com.stumbleupon.async.DeferredGroup$1Notify.call(DeferredGroup.java:82)

at com.stumbleupon.async.Deferred.doCall(Deferred.java:1278)

at com.stumbleupon.async.Deferred.runCallbacks(Deferred.java:1257)

at com.stumbleupon.async.Deferred.access$300(Deferred.java:430)

at com.stumbleupon.async.Deferred$Continue.call(Deferred.java:1366)

at com.stumbleupon.async.Deferred.doCall(Deferred.java:1278)

at com.stumbleupon.async.Deferred.runCallbacks(Deferred.java:1257)

at com.stumbleupon.async.Deferred.access$300(Deferred.java:430)

at com.stumbleupon.async.Deferred$Continue.call(Deferred.java:1366)

at com.stumbleupon.async.Deferred.doCall(Deferred.java:1278)

at com.stumbleupon.async.Deferred.runCallbacks(Deferred.java:1257)

...
....

Caused by: org.hbase.async.NonRecoverableException: Too many attempts: Exists(table="tsdb", key=[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 58, 65, 115, 121, 110, 99, 72, 66, 97, 115, 101, 126, 112, 114, 111, 98, 101, 126, 60, 59, 95, 60], family=null, qualifiers=null, attempt=11, region=null)

at org.hbase.async.HBaseClient.tooManyAttempts(HBaseClient.java:2556)

at org.hbase.async.HBaseClient.sendRpcToRegion(HBaseClient.java:2420)
```

Comment: What versions of everything are you running? What steps did you take to get that error?